# wxWidgets graphical designer suggestion

Tags: user-interface, wxwidgets

I am developing an application using wxWidgets for a first time. My favourite IDE is Code::Blocks. It has (or rather had) wxWidgets integration feature called wxSmith. However it seems deprecated at the moment. So I have few questions:

- Can wxSmith be adjusted to use wxWidgets 3.X?
- If yes how to do it, as simply setting up wxWidgets new projects causes some errors, and I am not sure if all components are presnet in toolboxes.
- If not what kind of graphical GUI designer would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about wxSmith but i would recommend [wxFormBuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/). It is pretty handy in generating gui.